# MDT 2013 Update 1 - Stalling at "Processing Bootstrap Settings"

Tags: windows, windows-10, images, deployment, mdt

**Current setup**

- Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) 2013 Update 1 (recently released version)
- All images done from Windows 10 Enterprise machine using HyperV
- Windows 10 and Windows 7 images and task sequences
- Windows 7 image works both deployment and capture of VM
- Windows 10 stock image (install.wim from ISO) deploys fine

**Goal**

- Deploy Windows 10 image from MDT
- Customize image (remove stuff, update stuff, install stuff)
- Recapture new Windows 10 image

**Problem**

Following the customization of the deployed image, the attempt to capture fails.  I take a snapshot first, then I map the drive to our network share, and can access it without issue.  I navigate to the scripts folder, and run litetouch.wsf.  **It stalls at "processing bootstrap settings".  The progress bar just doesnt move.

**What I've attempted so far**

- Running from the default administrator account, as well as a secondary account
- Regenerating the boot image completely
- Mapping to the IP instead of the FQDN
- Running the litetouch.wsf in a command line.

  - This produces a bit of text that you can see here [image: this screenshot]

**Question**

Since this is fairly new as far as updates go, there isn't much that I can find out there as to why my capture task sequence works with Windows 7, but fails to get past this part in Windows 10.  I can post my bootstrap.ini if requested (with identifying markouts)  The command window starts the "About to run command" portion, stalls for a second, and then gives me the "command completed" without the progress bar moving.

Anyone have any thoughts?

EDIT:  As requested, here is my bootstrap.ini:

> [Settings] Priority=Default
>
> [Default] DeployRoot=\IPOFMYMDTSERVER\CaptureShare
>
> UserDomain=OURDOMAIN

And here is the customsettings.ini file:

> [Settings]
>
> Priority=Default
>
> Properties=MyCustomProperty
>
> [Default]
>
> OSInstall=Y
>
> SkipCapture=NO
>
> SkipAdminPassword=NO
>
> SkipProductKey=YES
>
> SkipComputerBackup=YES
>
> SkipBitLocker=YES
>
> EventService=http://MDT:9800

I have kept both fairly simple.

Comment: Update 1 is the first version to support Windows 10, so some glitches might be expected. See [this blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/msdeployment/archive/2015/08/25/mdt-2013-update-1-release-notes-and-known-issues.aspx) and check your ADK version. The links [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mt240567.aspx) might also help. If still no go, you might require [this workaround](http://blog.westmonroepartners.com/make-the-microsoft-deployment-toolkit-mdt-2013-able-to-deploy-windows-10-windows-server-vnext-and-hyper-v-server-vnext-technical-preview/) that was for MDT 2013.

Comment: Can you post your bootstrap.ini and your CustomSettings.ini?

Comment: @AnthonyBartolo - Edited post to include those files.

Comment: Thanks @francisswest. One other question. When capturing the new image, are you running the LiteTouch.wsf with a Domain Account or the local Admin account?

Comment: I have tried with a secondary local admin account as well as the built in Administrator local account, both give the same results.  Have not tried a domain account as of yet.

Comment: Try using the domain account. I have been told that will address your issue.

Comment: @AnthonyBartolo - Just tried it with a domain account, no luck :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for this issue from a page specifying another issue.

> To workaround this error, simply create a .bat file in the root of
>   your Deployment Share to map the z: drive and call the Litetouch.wsf
>   script.  .Bat files can be Right-Clicked and “Run as Administrator”.

http://supportishere.com/429-createobjectmicrosoft-bdd-utilityactivex-component-cant-create-object-error-when-running-mdt-from-winvista-or-win7/

My .bat file ended up working when Run as Administrator was used.

Now on to the next deployment roadblock!